# Can't get magnificPopup to load an external content

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I am using `magnificPopup` to load an external page(from the same domain) and gets only the specific div.

```
// magnificPopup 
$('.signUpBut').magnificPopup({
  ajax: {
  } , callbacks: {
    parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
      mfpResponse.data = $(mfpResponse.data).find('.signupPage');
    }
  }
});
```

In the `console.log()` I get the following message:

> Ajax content loaded: Object {data: x.fn.x.init[0], xhr: Object}
>
> custom.js:26 [selector: ".signupPage", context: undefined]context: undefinedlength: 0selector: ".signupPage"**proto**: x[0]

The selector is correct, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've never used the ajax method on this plugin but from the documentation i think you need to `ajaxContentAdded: function() {
    // Ajax content is loaded and appended to DOM
    console.log(this.content);
  }`

do that and then `this.content` is what you've just modified so you append the data you want to a div like:

`$('.something').append(this.content)`